# How to install glib2.64 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gtk, glib, gnome

I have Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and installed glib version returned by `pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0` is **2.48.2**.

I want to install latest **glib 2.64** for my development uses.
I tried with `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev` but it is saying I have already latest version installed 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend upgrading to a later LTS version, or using a VM, a Docker container, or a Flatpak container.

If that's not possible, you might try building it and installing it yourself into a different prefix (configure with `meson -Dprefix=/opt/glib` or whatever). You could look into using a tool such as JHBuild to manage the prefix, but it might be more complicated than you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it from source: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/INSTALL.md